# Contextual closure type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void' expects 3 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body

Tags: ios, swift, closures, nsurlsession, urlsession

I am following this tutorial but getting this error:

> Contextual closure type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void' expects 3 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body

at line: `urlSession.dataTask(with: url) { (result)  in`

```swift
private func fetchResources<T: Decodable>(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Result<T, APIServiceError>) -> Void) {
    guard var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {
        completion(.failure(.invalidEndpoint))
        return
    }
    let queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "api_key", value: apiKey)]
    urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems
    guard let url = urlComponents.url else {
        completion(.failure(.invalidEndpoint))
        return
    }

    urlSession.dataTask(with: url) { (result)  in
        switch result {
            case .success(let (response, data)):
                guard let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode, 200..<299 ~= statusCode else {
                    completion(.failure(.invalidResponse))
                    return
                }
                do {
                    let values = try self.jsonDecoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
                    completion(.success(values))
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(.decodeError))
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(.apiError))
            }
     }.resume()
}
```

Comment: @Rob I fixed the parameters expected by URLSession but now the error is `Cannot find 'result' in scope' on the switch statement

Comment: This makes much more sense @Rob thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This closure of `dataTask` is expecting three parameters, a `Data?`, a `URLResponse?`, and an `Error?`. Your code is written as if this closure had a single parameter, a `Result`. It looks like you thought it was a `Result<(Data, URLResponse), Error>`, but it’s not. This `Result` enum is one that we use in our own code, but it’s not used by `URLSession`.

Thus, change [`dataTask`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1410330-datatask) to use a closure with the three parameters:

```swift
private func fetchResources<T: Decodable>(url: URL, completion: @escaping (Result<T, APIServiceError>) -> Void) {
    guard var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {
        completion(.failure(.invalidEndpoint))
        return
    }
    urlComponents.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "api_key", value: apiKey)]
    guard let url = urlComponents.url else {
        completion(.failure(.invalidEndpoint))
        return
    }

    urlSession.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            completion(.failure(.apiError))
            return
        }

        guard 
            let data = data,
            let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            200...299 ~= response.statusCode 
        else {
            completion(.failure(.invalidResponse))
            return
        }

        do {
            let values = try self.jsonDecoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
            completion(.success(values))
        } catch {
            completion(.failure(.decodeError))
        }
    }.resume()
}
```